# Errno 2 No such file or directory error while trying to execute Selenium Python program

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm learning Python and Selenium and I am facing a problem with my code while trying to execute Selenium Python program. The error is:

```
Errno 2 No such file or directory
```

Here is the snapshot of the error I'm facing:

[image: My problem here]

I'm trying to get selenium to boot chrome

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the location of the *Python Interpreter* within the ***Path*** variable as one of the *Environment Variables*. So *`python`* can be accessed for anywhere within your system.

Effectively, you need to append the following value in the *Path* variable:

```
C:\Users\rumi9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
```